# How can i export images with CSV file in php?

Tags: php, csv, export-to-excel

I am exporting CSV file correctly but i want to export images also what should i do?

Thanks in advance
Regards
kiran

Answer (score 4):

### Statement

You can't really have images in a CSV document in any logical way.

### Possibility 1

If it is an image hosted somewhere with a URL then you could include the URL as a value in the CSV.

### Possibility 2

Otherwise you could include the whole image as a base64 encoded string:

```
 $fh = fopen('/my/tmp/file.csv');
 $values['name'] = 'Kiran';
 $values['image'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents('/my/file/path.jpg'));
 fputcsv($fh, $fields);
```

Comment: hi Treffynon..thanks for ur replay..how to export images from source directory on button click? can u please tell me if know this? thanks in advance...

Comment: @kiran I would start a new question to address that as there is not enough room for details in comments. I also do not understand what you are asking so please try to explain it more in your next question.