# How to export image from RadGrid to csv file

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a `radgrid` which has an `image column`.
When I am exporting in `excel` format the image is showing in excel file,but when I am exporting it to `csv` file it is only showing the `image url` instead of the `image`.**Is there anyway to embed the image in `csv` file?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to break this to you, but there is not a direct way of storing image file in csv format. BUT... there are workarounds. Which I'm doubtful you'll find them... *appealing*.

1. Storing the image URL. You have already stated you didn't want it this way.
2. Base64 encoding. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016373/how-can-i-export-images-with-csv-file-in-php) that uses php. The problem with this one is base64 encoding requires more storage capacity than 8-bit data format.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**CSV** is a plain text file separated by commas and it does not support anything that is not text. However, there is a workaround like the one suggested by apollo and this is how you would want to code it.

```
//Display image and set the alternate text
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
          {
              GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
              System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)item["GridImageColumn"].Controls[0];
              //set image url                  
              img.ImageUrl = "~/images/test.png"; 

              /convert image to byte array and get the base64 representation
              byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/images/test.png"));
              string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);    

              img.AlternateText = base64ImageRepresentation; 
              }
    }

//Finally export the data
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)item["GridImageColumn"].Controls[0];
        item["GridImageColumn"].Text = img.AlternateText;
    }
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV();
}
```